# Java: Encapsulation and array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, encapsulation

I am making a tic-tac-toe game in Java to review some Java concepts and practice OOP.  So far I have 4 classes: `Board`, `Player`, `Coordinate`, and `Game`.  I am having problems testing the `Board` class.  A board consists of an array of coordinates.  There are currently two different constructor for `Board`.  The constructor that takes a single `Coordinate` was mainly made for testing purposes.

**Board.java**

```
public class Board {

    private Coordinate squares;
    private Coordinate[] coordinateSet;

    public Board(Coordinate squares) {
        this.squares = squares;
    }

    public Board(Coordinate[] coordinateSet) {
        this.coordinateSet = coordinateSet;
    }

    public Coordinate getSquares() {
        return squares;
    }

    public Coordinate[] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinateSet;
    }

    public Coordinate getCoordinate(int i) {
        return coordinateSet[i];
    }
}
```

**Coordinate.java**

```
public class Coordinate {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int xFlag; // 0 if available, 1 if not available
    private int yFlag; // 0 if available, 1 if not available
    private boolean squareAvailability;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y, int xFlag, int yFlag) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xFlag = xFlag;
        this.yFlag = yFlag;
    }

    public int getXCoordinate() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getYCoordinate() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getXFlag() {
        return xFlag;
    }

    public int getYFlag() {
        return yFlag;
    }

    public void setXFlag() {
        if(xFlag == 0) {
            xFlag = 1;
        } else { }
    }

    public void setYFlag() {
        if(yFlag == 0) {
            yFlag = 1;
        } else { }
    }

    public void add(Coordinate coordinate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean isSquareAvailable(Coordinate coordinate) {
        if(coordinate.getXFlag() == 0) {
            if(coordinate.getYFlag() == 0) {
                squareAvailability = true;
            } else {
                squareAvailability = false;
            }
        } else {
            squareAvailability = false;
        }       

        return squareAvailability;
    }

}
```

**BoardTest.java**

```
import edu.learning.tictactoe.Board;
import edu.learning.tictactoe.Coordinate;

public class BoardTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[9];   
        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                coordinates[i + j] = new Coordinate(i, j, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        Board board = new Board(coordinate);
        System.out.println(board.getSquares().getXCoordinate());
        Board board2 = new Board(coordinates);
        System.out.println(board2.getCoordinates().getCoordinate(0).getXCoordinate()); // error
    }
}
```

I get an error on the last line of `BoardTest.java` in my IDE that I `Cannot invoke getCoordinate(int) on the array type Coordinate[]`.  The problem is that I am trying to return a `Coordinate` object from an array of `Coordinate` objects, which isn't possible(?)  So how would I return a `Coordinate` from an array of `Coordinate`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`board.getCoordinates()` returns an array and the compiler error tells you that this array does not have a method `getCoordinate(int)`.

Simply write

```
board.getCoordinate(0).getXCoordinate()
```

if you want to access the coordinate via the array you could write

```
board.getCoordinates()[0].getXCoordinate()
```

Comment: Oops, in my code I was testing `board` twice, where I wanted to test `board2` on the last line, but your answer still works.